# Are SQL Server encryption functions deterministic?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, encryptbykey

I am learning about SQL Server encryption and I have a question regarding deterministic behaviour.

Are SQL Server encryption functions deterministic? Does it depend on the version (2005,..., 2017)?

I am not referring to 'Always encrypted' feature, but to functions like `encryptedbykey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this can be tested very easily. You can just encrypt the same value two times and check if the output is the same. Use the code below:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe';  

CREATE CERTIFICATE [CERT_StackOverflow]
WITH SUBJECT = 'example';

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY [SK_StackOverflow]   
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256  
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [CERT_StackOverflow];  
GO  


OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [SK_StackOverflow] DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [CERT_StackOverflow];  

SELECT EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SK_StackOverflow'), 'stackoverflow');  
SELECT EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SK_StackOverflow'), 'stackoverflow');  


DROP SYMMETRIC KEY [SK_StackOverflow];
DROP CERTIFICATE [CERT_StackOverflow];
DROP MASTER KEY;
```

So, the result is that the [ENCRYPTBYKEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function is not deterministic.

Why? It will be very easy to brute force if it were not. And if you are interested what is going on behind the scene, you can check the following [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2009/03/30/sql-server-encryptbykey-cryptographic-message-description/). 
Basically, the output text is calculated like this:

> CipherTextMessage := KeyGUID + EncryptionHeader + EncryptedMessage

where:

- KeyGUID := {16 bytes} Key_guid. This GUID serves as an identifier for the key and it is stored in metadata (SELECT key_guid FROM sys.symmetric_keys). It is used during decryption for finding the corresponding key in the key ring. That's why when we use [DECRYPTBYKEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decryptbykey-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) we do not use to specify the key used during the encryption
- EncryptedMessage is calculated like:

  > EncryptedMessage := InitializationVector + _EncryptFunction(SymKey,
  >   InitializationVector, InnerMessage)

And the key is the `InitializationVector` which is:

> InitializationVector := {1 block} the length of this field depends on
>   the algorithm being used. All AES family keys will be 16 bytes per
>   block, while the DES family keys are 8 bytes per block. Initialization
>   vectors are used to initialize the block algorithm. It is not intended
>   to be a secret, but must be unique for every call to the encryption
>   function in order to avoid revealing patterns.

If you are interested in deterministic encryption function, because of creating an index in order to optimize a search for example, and you do not want to use Always Encrypted because of all of its limitations, I can tell you how you can create/simulate deterministic encryption using the SQL Server [security hierarchy](https://aka.ms/sql-permissions-poster).

Comment: Re: Your first paragraph. It's worth noting that making two calls to a function and comparing the results can prove that a function is not deterministic, but not that it _is_ deterministic, e.g. `GetDate()` might return the same value for two calls. (Weekend reading: [The "BUG" Heard 'Round the World](https://cs162.eecs.berkeley.edu/static/readings/garman_bug_81.pdf).)

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, the planned introduction of [secure enclaves in SQL 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves) will remove some of the restrictions of AE columns, such as allowing one to search using inequality predicates on data encrypted with a randomized encryption key.

Comment: @HABO Yes, true. Dan Guzman - agree, you know Microsoft needs at least three major versions to make the things right (the column store indexes, the hekaton engine and now the AE).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I have executed the script in some SQL Server versions upto 2017 and functions are non-deterministic in all of them.

I am certainly interested in deterministic encryption since I have to encrypt some fields as first_name or identity_card which are typical fields you use to perform searchs for personal registers. In this scenario the possibility of indexing is desirable, and almost necessary.

Always Encripted is not a valid solutiion in this case since many agents may access the data in different manners.

Comment: @IgnacioJ You can accept this answer and check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892073/1080354 (let me know if you have any questions).

Comment: Hello. I am new here and didn't know about accepting. I accept it. Please, I would like to know a bit more about some manner to achieve deterministic encryption (without AE).